# imagemagick convert does not work through php

Tags: php, imagemagick

imagemagick convert does not work through php shell_exec but does through a shell.

In a shell `convert file.pdf file.png` works fine. But when I have this within a php file as `shell_exec('convert file.pdf file.png');` Then I get no output! I have the permissions to do this, so I think it isn't that that's the problem; I have checked the directory I am in by way of getcwd() and this is also ok.

I know shell_exec works because I have used it earlier in the code and that works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've been playing around for a while now and have discovered something: Doing a whoami on a shell returns geoff, yet through the php whoami returns nobody. Perhaps that is something to do with my problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8947959/815724) thanks to Crontab from another thread. I quote from there:

> [I]f you're trying to convert a PDF to a PNG using ImageMagick ...
>   even using the full path to ImageMagick's `convert` won't work if the
>   script's PATH doesn't contain the path location to Ghostscript also.
>   Without messing with any user paths, you could add:
>
> ```
> putenv("PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin");
> ```
>
> Or something similar depending on your setup. The `gs` executable has
>   to be in your script user's path somewhere or ImageMagick will fail to
>   convert PDF or EPS files.

Comment: Excellent.  Tried about 20 different ways before finding this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the full path to `convert`, i.e. `shell_exec('/usr/bin/convert file.pdf file.png);`. You can use `which convert` to find the location on your system.

Comment: Try full paths to the source and destination files, too.

Comment: What happens if you do `$result = shell_exec(...); print $result;`?

Comment: This doesn't return anything. I have since tried adding "  2>&1 1> /dev/null" (although I don't kno what this actually means) to the end of the command and have now got something to read into: sh: gs: command not found; convert: UnableToOpenConfigureFile; convert: PostscriptDelegateFailed; and finally convert: MissingAnImageFilename. I just give the first part of each of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reason why this could happen, but I suggest reading this page and the user comments:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php