# shell whoami doesn't equal php shell_exec whoami?

Tags: php, shell, imagemagick

In a shell I do simple whoami and I get geoff, which is good, since that's who I am.

In a php file I have shell_exec('whoami'); and I get nobody.

This seems to me to be a difference that could be explaining my original problem: imagemagick works from a shell but doesn't work from within a php script.

Now from working through this site I think this means that my apache xampp assigns a different user name rather than using my usual user name.

I have tried to change my login within the php by way of sudo but this isn't working for me as of yet.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't work, and the actual result you get?  You may need to specify the path to imagemagick when calling it from shell, and make sure you any directory it is trying to output to can be written by the user nobody.

Comment: User `nobody` probably has no `$PATH` or an incomplete `$PATH`. Specify the full path to the ImageMagick binaries when calling it from PHP.

Comment: `shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/convert -verbose /Users/geoff/Sites/Test/test.pdf  /Users/geoff/Sites/Test/result.png  2>&1 1> /dev/null');`  you mention output directory, can I choose this? Just to clarify, I already had full paths included, but it didn't work.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@anubhava is correct about why you get two different answers when you run `whoami`.  However, if you're trying to convert a PDF to a PNG using ImageMagick (like in your comment on the question), even using the full path to ImageMagick's `convert` won't work if the script's PATH doesn't contain the path location to Ghostscript also.  Without messing with any user paths, you could add:

```
putenv("PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin");
```

Or something similar depending on your setup.  The `gs` executable has to be in your script user's path somewhere or ImageMagick will fail to convert PDF or EPS files.

Comment: As soon as I read your comment I had a gut feeling that you have hit the nail on the head: and indeed it now works. Genius! Many thanks to you and for all who have helped.

Comment: @Geoff: glad to help.  I wrestled with that exact issue about a year ago.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

It should be simple to understand.

- In shell you are logged in as Unix user `geoff` and that's what you get.
- PHP is run in a httpd process in Unix which has `nobody` as the owner hence that's what you get when you `shell_exec('whoami');` from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The result from `whoami` you obtained simply means that your apache is running as `nobody`. This is as it should be and I strongly recommend not to change this.

The reason imagemagick doesn't work isn't probably directly related to the privileges with which your php code is run. There isn't enough information to diagnose the problem exactly, but it is most likely an executable or library search failure. Make sure that the binary and libraries are readable by `nobody` and that they are in a location where apache will find them. In particular ensure that `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are set up correctly.

Comment: This sounds promising. The error messages I got from the above code was: `UnableToOpenConfigureFile` and `PostscriptDelegateFailed` and `MissingAnImageFilename`. Where are the libraries?

Comment: In a few places like `/lib`, `/usr/lib` etc. For details see for example, `ld` manpage (precisely: description of the `-rpath-link` option), but with these error messages it doesn't seem to be a problem with libraries actually. It says that it can't find a config file, so you need to check where it is looking for it and make sure that it finds it (either by putting the config where expected or using an appropriate command line option to direct it to where the config is). In order to find out where it is looking for the config, try `strace`.

Answer (score 0):

1. add "2>&1" to your command
2. specify the full path to shell_exec(nobody has no $PAHT, so it just don't know where imagemagic binary is stored.
3. try to run the script as user on the console to see that is going wrong.