# Different results from running a script from command line and php

Tags: php, bash, shell

I'm trying to run a bash script from PHP. When I run it from a command prompt - everything works, when I pass the same command to exec() - something unexpected happens.

The script averages image files passed from the third argument. The first argument is directory, the second is the result file.

The bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$1
avg_file=$2
i=0
for file in "$@"; do
    if [ $i -eq 0 ]; then
        :
    elif [ $i -eq 1 ]; then
        :
    elif [ $i -eq 2 ]; then
    # If first file - just copy to result
        cp ${DIR}${file} ${DIR}${avg_file}
    else
    # Merge current file with result
        convert ${DIR}${file} ${DIR}${avg_file} -fx "(u+($i-2)*v)/$[$i-1]" ${DIR}${avg_file}
    fi
    i=$[$i+1]
done
```

When calling the script using the command line with:

`/path/to/script.sh /path/to/images average.png image/1.png image/2.png"`

it works fine and averages the images to average.png, but when called using PHP:

`exec("/path/to/script.sh /path/to/images average.png image/1.png image/2.png")`

it seems to replace average.png with the first passed image and thats it. I tried debugging it and it seems to go trough all the arguments.

What could be the cause of the problem?

*Edited: updated convert f-ion to how it actually looks

Comment: you could do that with php instead of bash

Comment: Print all the parameters passed : echo $@

Comment: @Dagon I might have to, because I really think I've run out of options here debugging that script.

Comment: its 'trival' to do in php and its easier to code in one language than in several at once

Comment: @crafter it prints all the arguments as they have been passed. I'm thinking it could be something with the convert function not working for whatever reason, because the result is replaced with the first file, meaning only "cp" works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've added `2>&1 1> /dev/null` at the end of the convert call and ran it again with php shell_exec. It outputted that the `convert` function could not be found, so I've added `putenv("PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin");` before the shell_exec call and now it works! Ideas from here: [imagemagick convert does not work through php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942695/imagemagick-convert-does-not-work-through-php)

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP script location as I see with

> average.png image/1.png image/2.png

You are using relative path, but you might want to use full path instead

Comment: I checked the path and everything was in order. Changed the script to use relative paths too and it worked the same. The above script uses absolute paths which it builds from the first argument though.